# How can I get the youtube live stream's latency information without selenium chromedriver?

Tags: python, youtube-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to fetch the livestreaming latency in twitch and youtube.

I resolved it for twitch with m3u8 file, however I can't resolve about it in youtube.

The best scenario is parse the "Live latency" in "stats for nerds" in youtube livestreaming video player, and it is okay to get the latency information in ['Normal', 'Low', 'Ultra low'].

But I can't find the youtube data api which returns the latency information, and also can't find with bs4.

I tried to get the exact m3u8 url of youtube livestreaming and get uptime to check the delay, but it failed.

I finally parsed the latency information successfully with selenium chromedriver, but my boss want another method because of the resource.

Comment: *I tried to get the exact m3u8 url of youtube livestreaming and get uptime to check the delay, but it failed.* May you precise why it failed?

Comment: I tried it with streamlink --stream-url "channel_name" and get the stream url, and used requests.get to get the playlist. With twitch url, it contains EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME but youtube-m3u8 I could not find it.

Comment: Does ``curl -s `yt-dlp -g 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID'` | grep 'EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME'`` solve your issue?

Comment: No. I think I need to handle m3u8 file once more to resolve it. It contains the m3u8 playlist, so I need to make request once more with it.